# Base class for component with a decorated method is not being picked up in the component that inherits from it

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-decorator, angular-inheritance

I'm using this code in my component to have a confirmation before the user refreshes the page, to avoid losing changes by mistake:

```js
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  unloadNotification($event: any) {
    if (!this.canDeactivate()) {
     $event.returnValue = '';
     $event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

To avoid duplicating that code in other components I wanted to create a base class like

```js
@Injectable()
export abstract class ComponentCanDeactivate {
  abstract canDeactivate(): boolean;

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  unloadNotification($event: any) {
    if (!this.canDeactivate()) {
      $event.returnValue = '';
      $event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

but now the components extending this base class, don't seem to be listening to the beforeunload event. Is the decorator not being picked by Angular because it is on the base class? I see this work in this: [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksm9gx?file=app%2Fcan-deactivate%2Fcomponent-can-deactivate.ts) using angular 11, and I'm using angular 13. don't know if that changed the behavior or if I'm missing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the abstract class to be a `Component` rather than an `Injectable`

```js
@Component({ template: '' })
export abstract class ComponentCanDeactivate {
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xsmfdn?file=src/app/concrete/concrete.component.ts

Angular supports inheriting `HostListener` but seems to get confused when you mix decorators like that.

Comment: It works with the @ Component instead of @ Injectable, thanks. I initially added it because I was getting an: 'Error NG2007: Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.' and in another SO answer it was mentioned that @ Injectable was a way to fix it.